# Do I only need to import style.css for a child theme?

Tags: css, child-theme

I am creating a child theme for the first time, and sort of learning as I go.

I am having an issue with the way videos are showing up on a mobile phone with my child theme, but not with my parent theme. I'm wondering what is going on.

On my child theme the videos show up large when viewed on a mobile device (http://wpdallas.com/test)

However, in the parent theme the videos show up fine: http://wpdallas.com/plain

In my child them I am importing the following css, do I need to import every CSS file into my child theme, or just the style.css? (I've found conflicting info when learning how to do this.)The parent theme has about 20 different css files. I'm wondering if I need to import them all into my child theme, or if I need to delete the other two below, and just leave the first one (style.css.)

Just trying to figure out why the child theme isn't styling correctly. Thanks.

```
 @import url("../Standard/style.css");
    @import url("../Standard/standard_framework/css/standard_framework.css"); 
    @import url("../Standard/css/lib/adapt/mobile.css");
```

Comment: What is the parent theme you're using? It shouldn't be that you need to include 1 for the core, but some theme devs do some weird stuff and so it may be a different situation. Also, you're probably not gonna get many responses with a 25% accept rate, you should go and resolve some of your old questions.

Comment: The parent theme I'm using isn't a public theme, so that wouldn't help you. I can post any of the code in here. Can you tell why the one at /plain shows up fine in a mobile browser, but not the one at /test?  Also how do I go and resolve the old questions?

Comment: In that case, this sounds like a user support question that should be addressed to the theme's developer(s)

Comment: The theme really isn't child theme ready right now. I added some code that allowed it to be child theme ready. I'm just asking in general when making a child theme, do I need to import more than just the style.css? Here is the code from the theme I put into make it use a child theme.  // theme
  wp_register_style('standard', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('standard');   Also how do I resolved a question? I thought I just select the check mark. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: Yep, just select the right answer (or post your own answer if one didn't come and you resolved the issue). I'm not sure what that code is supposed to be...have you read [the codex page on child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)?

Comment: @m0r7if3r yelp. I have it set up correctly, I'm just not sure if I"m supposed to import every .css file, or just the main one. Do you have a lot of experience working with Child themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question depends **entirely** on the Theme in question, and how it handles CSS.

1. For a Theme that uses *only* a single `style.css` file, obviously, you only need to import `style.css`.
2. For a Theme that links other stylesheets in the document head (they shouldn't be doing this; instead, they should be properly *enqueueing* them), you'll need to determine whether or not you want to leave those links in `header.php`, based on whether or not you want to *use* the styles defined in those stylesheets.
3. For a Theme that *enqueues* additional stylesheets, via `wp_enqueue_style()`, you don't need to do anything. Such stylesheets will continue to be enqueued in the Child Theme. If you *don't want* those styles, then you need to *dequeue* those stylesheets, via `wp_dequeue_style()` in the Child Theme `functions.php`.
4. For a Theme that *prints* styles in the document head, via `add_action( 'wp_print_styles', $callback )`, you don't need to do anything. Such stylesheets will continue to be printed in the Child Theme. If you *don't want* those styles, then you need to *override the output of* those stylesheets, via `remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', $callback )` in the Child Theme `functions.php`.

I *think* that covers most of the bases.

Comment: is there any way we could do a chat? I want to ask you a few questions about what you talked about here. :) Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to pop into chat.