# All of my custom Bootstrap styles are not working in my child theme!

Tags: css, child-theme, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a child theme for Betheme.

I styled most of the elements in my child theme using Bootstrap separately as HTML templates and later integrated with my child theme.

But, none of them worked!

It is now in their default styles.

What I did is that I downloaded Bootstrap.min.css file into my child theme and imported that into the style.css file with @import();

I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it as I'm a newbie at Wordpress. Or it has something to do with the parent theme.

As I said, when these bootstrap elements are out of WordPress in an HTML file, it works just fine. So I'm guessing that I import the Bootstrap files into my child theme in the wrong way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43690/do-i-only-need-to-import-style-css-for-a-child-theme?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In your child theme's `function.php` file, find the enqueue function and add it there instead of using `@import` in your CSS.

For example:

```
function my_scripts_and_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array( 'main-style', '', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_styles' );
```

What this function will do is load your `style.css` file, then load `bootstrap.min.css` only if `style.css` is successfully loaded (NOTE: It assumes `bootstrap.min.css` is located in `/wp-content/themes/{your theme}/css` so adjust that code accordingly.

`wp_head()` will take it from there. If you need bootstrap to load first, then move the `array()` argument to `main-style` and change the contents to `'bootstrap-style'`.

Comment: Hi, I did the same with the correct directory path but the web page gives an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Hi, Now that HTTP 500 error is gone, but still the bootstrap styles are not working!

Comment: View the source code of the page and check for the link to your bootstrap css file. If it's there, click on it to see if it will load.

Comment: where are your bootstrap assets located? Are they located within the main theme folder or within your child theme folder? If the latter then you need to change get_template_directory_uri to get_stylesheet_directory_uri instead